# Java Derby does not find database

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

Java Derby does not find a database even with "create=true" sentence.

The code is following:

```
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:javaDb;create=true");
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

In CMD, from libs folder:

> ```
> java -jar derbyrun.jar ij
> version ij 10.15
> connect 'jdbc:derby:javaDb';
> ERROR XJ004: Database 'javaDb' not found.
> show connections
> No connection available.
> ```

Answer (score 2):

If I have interpreted your question correctly...

**Quick Answer**

(a) Run the `ij` start-up command in the same location where your Java program created the new database (see below).

or

(b) Create the DB using `ij` at the same time as you connect to it (also see below).

---

**More Notes**

When you create a new Derby DB using the Java code in your question, that will create the DB in the root folder of where the code (the Java project) was executed.

Look for a `javaDb` folder there, containing the Derby database files.

But when you try to connect to that database at the `ij>` command prompt, after running this:

```
java -jar derbyrun.jar ij
```

...and then using `connect 'jdbc:derby:javaDb';` you are telling `ij` that the DB is in the `lib` directory of the Derby installation folder.

Those are probably two different locations - hence you get your "not found" error.

You can locate and copy the `javaDb` folder from where it was created (your Java app) to the Derby installation's `lib` folder. But probably not a good idea. You should keep the `lib` folder clean.

Alternatively...

You can execute the `java -jar derbyrun.jar ij` command from the parent folder of where the `javaDb` folder is located (i.e. from your Java project root folder:

```
java -jar %DERBY_HOME%\lib\derbyrun.jar ij
```

(I am assuming that by "CMD" you mean a Windows command prompt.)

If `DERBY_HOME` is not defined, then just use the full path to the Derby `lib` folder.

Then, at the `ij>` prompt, retry your connection command:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:javaDb';
```

So, for example, for me, the Java command is this:

```
java -jar C:\derbydb\db-derby-10.16.1.1-bin\lib\derbyrun.jar ij
```

And I run the above command from where my Java project is located:

```
C:\Users\me\Documents\JavaDerbyDemo
```

---

**Use `ij` For DB Creation**

What you maybe want to do instead of all of the above is to use `ij` to actually *create* the DB as you first try to connect to it in `ij`:

```
connect 'jdbc:derby:javaDbTwo;create=true';
```

That will create a `javaDbTwo` folder (containing your new, empty Derby DB) in the same location where you run the command.